# Are there any possibilities of upgrading OpenDJ LDAP with minimalistic downtime?

Tags: ldap, openldap, opendj

I am planning to update LDAP OpenDJ 2.6.4 version to OpenDJ 4.4.11 version. Is there any recommended way to migrate the data to the new OpenDJ 4.4.11 LDAP server with minimalistic downtime?

The expectation is to migrate the data records to OpenDJ 4.4.11 version, with minimum downtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenDJ supports replication of data between servers of different versions.
And it also supports easy upgrade from version 2 to version 4.
If you have setup high availability through replicated servers, you should be able to upgrade with no downtime of the service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Easy upgrade means Can I update the version 2 server itself to version 4 without having any impact on the data?

Comment: Correct, data is safe when upgrading OpenDJ.